# Whenever i am trying to make ionic3 build it comes up with "custom component error"

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

I am using **ionic3** and wanted to make a production build, I also create a custom component by using the command line.

But whenever I am going to make a build it comes up with the custom component error I also attached an image and paste in blockquote of the error which I got.
[Image of the errors which I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCeKL.png)

> ngc started ...
>      typescript error
>               Can't bind to 'control' since it isn't a known property of 'control-messages'. 1. If 'control-messages' is
>               an Angular component and it has 'control' input, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If
>               'control-messages' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this
>               component to suppress this message. 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the
>               '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("  
>               ][control]="userForm.controls.fname">

**Here is my component.module.ts code**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ControlMessageComponent } from './control-message/control-message';
@NgModule({
 imports: [IonicModule],
 declarations: [ControlMessageComponent],
 exports: [ControlMessageComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

**and here is my App.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { BundlesAssortedPage } from '../pages/bundles-assorted/bundles-assorted';
import { AllCategoriesPage } from '../pages/all-categories/all-categories';
import { MyCartPage } from '../pages/my-cart/my-cart';
import { CheckoutPage } from '../pages/checkout/checkout';
import { CategoryDetailPage } from '../pages/category-detail/category-detail';
import { MyAddressesPage } from '../pages/my-addresses/my-addresses';
import { AddRemovePopoverPage } from '../pages/add-remove-popover/add-remove-popover';
import { OrderHistoryPage } from '../pages/order-history/order-history';
import { ReOrderDetailsPage } from '../pages/re-order-details/re-order-details';
import { OurLocationPage } from '../pages/our-location/our-location';
import { MyFavouritesPage } from '../pages/my-favourites/my-favourites';
import { SignupPage } from '../pages/signup/signup';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { ServicesProvider } from '../providers/services/services';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { ProductWizardPage } from '../pages/product-wizard/product-wizard';
import { ForgotPasswordPage } from '../pages/forgot-password/forgot-password';
import { AccountVerificationPage } from '../pages/account-verification/account-verification';
import { NetworkProvider } from '../providers/network/network';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { ProductDetailsPage } from '../pages/product-details/product-details';
import { AddAddressPage } from '../pages/modal/add-address/add-address';
import { GlobalStringsProvider } from '../providers/global-strings/global-strings';
import { OrderReviewPage } from '../pages/order-review/order-review';
import { OrderThankyouPage } from '../pages/order-thankyou/order-thankyou';
import { ValidationService } from '../providers/services/validation-service';
import { ControlMessageComponent } from '../components/control-message/control-message';
import { ionicComponents } from '../providers/ionic-components/ionic-components';
import { DesignPizzaPage } from '../pages/design-pizza/design-pizza';
import {  Connectivity } from '../providers/connectivity-service/connectivity-service';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { StoreInfoModalPage } from '../pages/store-info-modal/store-info-modal';
import { AccountSettingsPage } from '../pages/account-settings/account-settings';
import { ComboDetailsPage } from '../pages/combo-details/combo-details';
import { PhoneVerificationPage } from '../pages/phone-verification/phone-verification';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    // HomePage,
    // BundlesAssortedPage,
    // ComboDetailsPage,
    // StoreInfoModalPage,
    // AllCategoriesPage,
    // ProductWizardPage,
    // CategoryDetailPage,
    // ProductDetailsPage,
    // MyCartPage,
    // DesignPizzaPage,
    // CheckoutPage,
    // OrderReviewPage,
    // OrderThankyouPage,
    // AddAddressPage,
    // MyAddressesPage,
    // AddRemovePopoverPage,
    // OrderHistoryPage,
    // ReOrderDetailsPage,
    // OurLocationPage,
    // MyFavouritesPage,
    // AccountSettingsPage,
    // LoginPage,
    // SignupPage,
    // PhoneVerificationPage,
    // ForgotPasswordPage,
    // AccountVerificationPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    // HomePage,
    // BundlesAssortedPage,
    // ComboDetailsPage,
    // StoreInfoModalPage,
    // AllCategoriesPage,
    // ProductWizardPage,
    // CategoryDetailPage,
    // ProductDetailsPage,
    // MyCartPage,
    // DesignPizzaPage,
    // CheckoutPage,
    // OrderReviewPage,
    // OrderThankyouPage,
    // AddAddressPage,
    // AddRemovePopoverPage,
    // MyAddressesPage,
    // AddRemovePopoverPage,
    // OrderHistoryPage,
    // ReOrderDetailsPage,
    // OurLocationPage,
    // MyFavouritesPage,
    // AccountSettingsPage,
    // LoginPage,
    // SignupPage,
    // PhoneVerificationPage,
    // ForgotPasswordPage,
    // AccountVerificationPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    ValidationService,
    ionicComponents,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ServicesProvider,
    Network,
    NetworkProvider,
    GlobalStringsProvider,
    Connectivity,
    Geolocation
    
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If someone can help me it will really appriciated 
Kind Regards

Comment: are you using lazy loading in your app?

Comment: no, I am not using lazy loading.

Comment: then, I think you should import your component in ` app.module.ts` (which you have done already) and add it in declaration

Comment: @NitinP, I did this too but it comes up with an error again

Comment: Here is the error which I got after declaration.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577272/whenever-i-am-trying-to-make-ionic3-production-build-it-comes-up-with-custom-co

Comment: link is broken, please correct it

Comment: the above question is deleted that's why it's broken meanwhile i got the same error after declaration please advice

Comment: unless and until you post error, we cant help you

Comment: @NitinP Please take a look i placed error in my question detail.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's listen to your error and add the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to your **main** `NgModule`, so place this in `app.module.ts`

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  schemas: [
     CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
   ],
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    ValidationService,
    ionicComponents,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ServicesProvider,
    Network,
    NetworkProvider,
    GlobalStringsProvider,
    Connectivity,
    Geolocation

  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me it comes with the same error. Please advice .

Comment: @Hamza_Idrees alright, updated the answer with the second part of the errormessage. If you add the `schema` property with these Schemas to **app.module.ts** your shouldn't experience the same error. Btw, do you load `component.module.ts` into `app.module.ts`? Because you should

Comment: Whenever I include componenent.module.ts it will come with these error bellow

`Type ControlMessagesComponent in E:/ionic/ecomerece-app/src/components/control-messages/control-messages.ts
            is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ComponentsModule in
            E:/ionic/ecomerece-app/src/components/components.module.ts and LoginPageModule in`